# How can I count these numbers which are larger than 12th element in my array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, count

So I created an array with 16 elements and I want to count the number of elements that are greater than the 12th element of the array. I know that I need to use for and if. I tried it in many ways,but I always get 0 as a result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define MERET 16

int main()
{

    int tomb[MERET];
    int i;
    printf("Kerem az elemeket:\n");
    for(i=0; i<MERET; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &tomb[i]);
    }
    printf("%d \n",&tomb[16]);


    int szamlalo=0;
    for(i=0;i<MERET;i++)
    {
        if(tomb[12]<i)
            szamlalo++;
    }
    printf("talalatok szama %d\n", szamlalo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tomb[12]<i` ==> `tomb[12]<tomb[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the other values of the array with the 12th value. The problem here is you are comparing: `if(tomb[12]<i)`

Change the

```
for(i=0;i<MERET;i++)
{
    if(tomb[12]<i)
    szamlalo++;
}
```

with

```
for(i=0;i<MERET;i++)
{
    if(tomb[12]<tomb[i])
    szamlalo++;
}
```

Comment: Actually you need to update your question and add some other things like: Input to the array and output also.